# What are good beginner books to follow for classical guitar (self study or otherwise) ?

Tags: learning, classical-guitar, books

I've come across a lot of different series and 'methodologies' (Aaron Shearer, Mel Bay etc) books - and it's very confusing for the beginner when there's no teacher to guide him or her.

Comment: related: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/1977/1344

Answer (score 3):

For classic guitar I recommend:

- [The Christopher Parkening Guitar Method, Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142343417X)
- The Christopher Parkening Guitar Method, Vol. 2

These were published in the early 1970s by the great virtuoso Christopher Parkening with Jack Marshall and David Brandon. They are highly regarded by guitar teachers. The newest edition comes with a CD so you can hear what the lessons sound like when they are played correctly.

From the publisher's description: "The method covers: rudiments of classical technique, note reading and music theory, selection and care of guitars, strategies for effective practicing, and much more. The CD includes 99 demonstration tracks."

Comment: Why the down vote my dear down voter? It is better to provide some explanation than this arbitrary vote.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the answer would be helpful if you can elaborate on why you think these books are good.

Comment: Upvote for reminding me of this good (according to my subjective memory!) resource... though I can't elaborate on why either!

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have access to a teacher, I recommend choosing a program that will provide you with corrective feedback so that you may fix your mistakes in order to progress. In my experience, lacking this feedback you may unknowingly develop poor habits, both musically and technically.

Fixing your mistakes requires seeing and hearing correct playing. So, a multimedia instructional program may be your best choice. I recommend looking at Frederick Noad's books with CDs/DVDs. (He published his first multimedia instructional program in 1963, which came in the form of a book and weekly television program. See [attached photo](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/2dK-x0-Lf-MXShB9f5Xthg?feat=directlink) of my copy.) Today, you would probably do well to try Noad's updated text:

[http://www.amazon.com/Solo-Guitar-Playing-Book-Classical/dp/0825694000/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1310553812&sr=8-7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0825694000)

Noad's books are well-respected by many classical guitar teachers. So, if you decide to ultimately take lessons, you may find the transition to be a smooth one.

Comment: +1. I do have a teacher, but he has not really laid out a structured program for me. Unfortunately, this is the best I can get right now. So yes, DVDs are helpful. I've looked at a few, including William Kanengiser's videos. But I still don't see any way around the feedback aspect - that can only come from a teacher.

Answer (score 3):

I havent looked at beginner books recently. But I can offer a *rule of thumb*:

- A *Real* Classical Guitar Book will contain no tablature. It is very important to "take the plunge" and master staff notation.

The book I used and was very happy with was [The Romero Method, by Celedonio Romero](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000P1OUQE), but it looks like it's out of print. :(

There is a book by [*Son of* Romero](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0985945109) that's probably worth checking out. (These guys were breaking into The Tonight Show, while Segovia was breaking into Carnegie Hall.)

Comment: upvoted b/c good rule of thumb; no opinion on the books mentioned (I haven't read them)

Answer (score 2):

As one who is teaching himself to play classical guitar, I have found the following method books to be excellent. They are in no order:

Frederick Noad. Solo Guitar Playing: A complete course of instruction in the techniques of guitar performance* (4th Ed).

Aaron Shearer. Classic Guitar Technique (3rd Ed). Book and CD. (ISBN-10: 07390-57103).

Julio Sagreras.  Mel Bay Julio S. Sagreras Guitar Lessons: Books 1-3 (English and Spanish Edition) [Spiral-bound]. (ISBN-10: 0786627239).

Jeffrey Goodman.  A Beginner’s Guide to the Classical Guitar. (ISBN-10: 1439267499).

Robert Benedict. Sight Reading for the Classical Guitar, Level I-III.(ISBN-10: 0769209742).

Robert Benedict. Sight Reading for the Classical Guitar, Level IV-V. (ISBN-10: 0769212859).

Answer (score 1):

The Aaron Shearer series of books ([link to Volume 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007FLIM2)) are well-regarded standards. They were first published in the 1950s or 1960s and are still in print.